# How to pass a char as an argument of a function inside a class using template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I'm trying to pass a char array into a function(push) inside this class(BaseStack):

```
template < class T >
class BaseStack
{
  void push(const T&item){
     //Ignore
    }

}
```

What I tried was:

```
char finalstring[L];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) 
  finalstring[i] = 'x';

BaseStack<char> c;
c.push(finalstring);
```

But my compiler said that I was doing an invalid conversion

Comment: the type of `finalstring` is not `char`, its `char[L]` (which in many situation decays to `char*`) since that is not the same as `char`, you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 BaseStack<char> c;
```

This means that your template parameter is `char`. This is what you specified for the template parameter. Therefore, the instance of your template is, in so many words, and ***very*** loosely speaking:

```
class BaseStack
{
  void push(const char &item){
     //Ignore
    }
 }
```

This is what happens, since your template parameter is a `char`. `T` is char, and since the parameter in the template is `void push(const T &item)`, then that's what you get.

```
 c.push(finalstring);
```

`finalstring` is a `char` array, which decays to a `char *`. This attempts to pass a `char *` to a class method that takes a (`const` refence to a) `char`. This is not allowed in C++, and that's the reason for your compilation error.

It is unclear what your intent is here, whether the template parameter should be either a `const T *`, or you need to pass `finalstring`'s first character, only. Doing either will solve this particular compilation error.

Comment: Thanks! By only passing finalstring's first character only, will this mean that I would be passing it as a char or as a reference to the first element of the array?

Comment: As defined, you will be passing a reference to the first character in the array. And since the function receives it as a reference to a `const` object, `push()` will not be able to modify it.